# Function to read file passing it by parameter

Tags: java, file, char, return

Hi guys I'm having difficulty with a method to read file.I have not found anything in the documentation.

I'm trying to return an array of char.

```
public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        File  f = new File("word.txt");
     
        char [] word=ReadWordFile(f);
        
        System.out.println(word);

    }
    
    
    //1.Read words  from File and return as arr of char
    public static  char [] ReadWordFile(File f) throws IOException {
         BufferedReader br
         = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
         
         char [] aux = null;

     // Declaring a string variable
     String st;
     // Condition holds true till
     // there is character in a string
     while ((st = br.readLine()) != null)

        st+=aux;

     return aux;    
    }
```

Comment: *//1.Read words  from File and return as arr of char* If the file contained only the word 'cat', what would your array be? You should probably post an example file too

Comment: yes any word  like you say for example  a file called word.txt and inside the word cat so the array have char [ ] word ={ 'c', 'a' ,'t' };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing changes `aux` in your code:

```
char [] aux = null;
// Declaring a string variable
String st;
// Condition holds true till
// there is character in a string
while ((st = br.readLine()) != null)
  st+=aux;
return aux;
```

Concatenate all read strings and then get the char array from:

```
String st = "", read = null;
// Condition holds true till
// there is character in a string
while ((read = br.readLine()) != null)
  st += read;
return st.toCharArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is very useful.
If I understand correctly instead of trying to save it in a char array directly we save it in a String and we pass it to char array with the method.
Best regards

Comment: *st+=aux;* of course makes no sense so probably not a good idea to quote it. So, when you've got all the words into the array, how do you know where one begins and ends?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above, if you have a file containing words on each line, you're not going to to be able to distinguish the beginnings and endings of words if you put everything into one `char[]`. You *can* use `char[][]` though, so something like:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Words {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of(args[0])))) {
            char[][] words = sc.tokens()
                .map(String::toCharArray)
                .toArray(char[][]::new);
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(words));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I finally understood what you meant. It is true with the way we are reading it only takes the last word.I couldn't understand the example you gave.
Could you update the code by adding it in an individual method. and where do we specify the file path ?
Regards.

Comment: There's a complete app. Pass the path to the file as an argument when running it